# Is there a way for scraping a specific table row or table cell with powershell?

Tags: powershell, web-scraping, invoke-webrequest

I'm coding a web-scraper with PowerShell and want to select a specific value in a table or the whole row.

What I've managed already is to print out my values but it selects the column names and the values which is not desired. This could be because I've selected `tagName('div')` but I don't know what else I can select; `Table` wont be appropriate since there are multiple tables without `className` or `id`s.

```bsh
$w = Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://localhost:80/index.html"

$values = $w.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("div") | Where { $_.Id -eq "disk" }

foreach ($val in $values)
{
    Write-Host $val.innertext
}
```

I expect the output to be:

```
Car
Red
Audi
```

But the output is:

```
VehicleColorBrand
CarRedAudi
```

Comment: To have a better overview, run get-member after $values, so you get what sort of information can be extracted.

Comment: Or use [ConvertTo-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6) or [ConvertTo-Expression](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression) to understand the full hierarchy.

Comment: can we see the html in question?